# Django multiple forms, one form resets other form

Tags: python, django

Got some forms in my view...
I want that only what I have submitted is changed in the database. So that no forms overwrite each other. How can I do this with my view?

I even noticed that the order in which each '..._form.is_valid()' is, makes a difference in what gets overwritten

views.py

```
@login_required
def DashboardView(request):

    browser = str(request.user_agent.browser.family)

    user = str(request.user)
    short_user = user[0:7] + "..."

    try:
        radius = request.user.fieldradius
    except FieldRadius.DoesNotExist:
        radius = FieldRadius(user=request.user)

    try:
        font_size = request.user.fontsize
    except FontSize.DoesNotExist:
        font_size = FontSize(user=request.user)

    try:
        change_color = request.user.colors
    except Colors.DoesNotExist:
        change_color = Colors(user=request.user)

    try:
        toggle_settings = request.user.togglesettings
    except ToggleSettings.DoesNotExist:
        toggle_settings = ToggleSettings(user=request.user)

    try:
        page_details = request.user.pagedetails
    except PageDetails.DoesNotExist:
        page_details = PageDetails(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FieldForm(request.POST, instance=Field(user=request.user))
        togglesettings_form = ToggleSettingsForm(
            request.POST, instance=toggle_settings)

        radius_form = FieldRadiusForm(request.POST, instance=radius)
        change_color_form = ColorsForm(request.POST, instance=change_color)
        fontsize_form = FontSizeForm(request.POST, instance=font_size)
        pagedetails_form = PageDetailsForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=page_details)

        if togglesettings_form.is_valid():
            togglesettings_form.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard/#panel1')

        if form.is_valid():
            time.sleep(1.5)
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.creator_adress = get_client_ip(request)
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard')

        if radius_form.is_valid():
            radius_form.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard')

        if fontsize_form.is_valid():
            fontsize_form.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard')

        if change_color_form.is_valid():
            change_color_form.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard')

        if pagedetails_form.is_valid():
            pagedetails_form.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard')

    else:
        form = FieldForm()
        radius_form = FieldRadiusForm(instance=radius)
        fontsize_form = FontSizeForm(instance=font_size)
        change_color_form = ColorsForm(instance=change_color)
        pagedetails_form = PageDetailsForm(instance=page_details)
        togglesettings_form = ToggleSettingsForm()

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'form': form, 'togglesettings_form': togglesettings_form, 'fontsize_form': fontsize_form, 'change_color_form': change_color_form, 'browser': browser, 'short_user': short_user, 'radius_form': radius_form, 'radius': radius, 'pagedetails_form': pagedetails_form})
```

If I submit a form, for example the togglesettings_form, it looks like this in the database:

[image]

After that, I submit another form, for example the fontsize_form. The fontsize_form will be saved but then the togglesettings_form will be resetted:

[image]

Forms and models, if you want to see them:
https://pastebin.com/PhaFCdBP

I have read something like

if ...form in request.POST:
do this

But I dont know how to implement that in my view

Comment: Is there a reason why you're creating 6 different non-abstract models instead of one Settings model with appended attributes?

Comment: That just fit better

Answer (score 0):

Usually I name the submit button on the form something like "my-form"

Then you can just go:

```
if "my-form" in request.POST:
   then do what you need to do
```

View example:

```
 if 'load_doc' in request.POST:               
                file = request.FILES['document_file']
                doc = documents(client=current_client,document_name=request.POST['document_name'],document_file=file)
                doc.save()
```

html example:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="panel-body">{{ single_load_form|crispy }}</div>
<div class="panel-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="load_doc">Submit</button></form></div>
```